# Does Ubuntu work on the Asus F552CL-X211H?

Tags: 15.04, asus

Recently, I decided to put Linux Ubuntu on my laptop ASUS F552CL-X211H.
Tell me whether Linux Ubuntu will work on this laptop.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have an Asus F552C, I know the nomenclature slightly varies across countries and across minor revisions; could you post the output of `lspci` so I can verify it's the exact same laptop? This is one of the multiple Italian subversions of the X550CL family.

Comment: But I have now is a Windows

Comment: Any Ubuntu version will do. Install 14.04.3 LTS.

Comment: RIght. Does the laptop match [these](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12997812/) specs? (roughly, I mean expecially the wireless card)

Comment: If there is Mediatek wifi, 15.10 will be better.

Comment: I should MT-7630e

Comment: By the way, I forgot to ask, and whether to update the BIOS before installing Linux?

Comment: I'm almost sure it's the same laptop aside from maybe the hard disk size, because I checked the box and the serial number reports F552CL, despite F552C being written on the sticker. I left an answer, everything works out of the box but the wifi and bluetooth drivers, which anyway are easily installable by cloning a GitHub repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have almost the exact same laptop, if not exactly the same (for what is worth about compatibilty, i.e. the wifi and bluetooth adapters: ASUS F552C).

Everything worked out of the box in Trusty, Vivid and Wily, except the wifi and the bluetooth adapters, which are both easily installable by installing `git` and running a single command;

First, install `git`:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Then clone the GitHub repository for the wireless and bluetooth drivers and install the drivers using this command:

```
git clone https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E.git; cd MT7630E; sudo bash install
```

Comment: A single command...?

Comment: @Jos Fair enough, they're three commands. However I rather meant that copy-pasting a single line will download and install the drivers all at once.